# A little program that I can't understand its result

Tags: c

I can't understand why the following program outputs 5,6 instead of 6,6

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a=5,b=6,*ptr1,*ptr2;
    ptr1=&b;
    ptr2=ptr1;
    *++ptr2=6;
    printf("%d,%d",a,b);
}
```

At first `ptr2` has the address of `b`, then we're going to increment its value in the line `*++ptr2=6;` which will make it take the address of `a`,so  then `*ptr2=6` is equivalent to `a=6`.

Comment: It is by chance. Scalar variable can be treated as one-element array in pointer arithmetics. Adding one (incrementing) to `ptr2` moves the pointer one element after the last (the only) element. Making that pointer is legal, but dereferencing that is illegal.

Comment: You are requesting to output `a` and `b`, with `printf("%d,%d",a,b);`, but `a` according to the code, is never modified. So it prints the initialized value.

Comment: i didn't understand your explanation fully, but does it mean that sometimes it will outupt 6,6?

Comment: @Gealber isn't ptr2 going to have the address of a after we increment it ?

Comment: You are moving the pointer to the address immediately after that of `b`, then de-referencing it, and assigning a value of 6. The behavior is not defined. If by chance the scalar `a` is stored in the address immediately after `b`, then `ptr2` will reference that variable, and so both scalars will have the value of 6.

Comment: @zakariakais not necessarily. The spec does not guarantee any relative locality of scalar variables in memory. Initializing them both in the same line does not mean they will be adjacent in memory.

Comment: @zr0gravity7 oh ok, i didn't actually add a little detail of the exercice:
assuming that &a=28FF44 and &b=28FF40

Comment: as @zr0gravity7 point it out, they don't need to be allocated adjacently in memory.

Comment: Don't go finding out how things that aren't guaranteed to work actually do work.  Find out how things that _are_ guaranteed to work actually work, and make sure you don't experiment with undefined behaviour (or, at least, don't come plaguing SO with questions about undefined behaviour — there is no useful answer that can be given).

Comment: Note that the compiler is entitled to optimize the variable `a` out of existence.  It could simply pass a literal `5` to the call to `printf()` because there is no code that changes the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the result by chance.

The address of `b` is assigned to `ptr2` via `ptr1`.
Scalar variables like `b` here can be treated as one-element array in pointer arithmetics.

Adding one (incrementing) to `ptr2` moves the pointer one element after the last (the only) element. Making that pointer is legal, but dereferencing that is illegal.

You invoked *undefined behavior* by performing out-of-range access.